# Is it possible to run Minecraft on AGP Aperture Size?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I want to force Minecraft to use AGP Aperture Size. I played Minecraft on GeForce4 MX with AGPX8 (64 mb) but it burned one day so now I am using builded-in videocard. My current AGP Aperture Size is set to 64 mb.
My specs:

```
Motherboard Name: Hewlett-Packard HP d530 SFF(PE095S)

Videocard: Intel(R) 82865G Graphics Controller (Built-in)
Memory Size: 96 MB

RAM
Module Name - Kingston K
Memory Type - DDR SDRAM
Memory Speed - PC3200 (200 MHz)
  Memory Timings
    @ 200 MHz   3.0-3-3-8  (CL-RCD-RP-RAS) / 11-14-2  (RC-RFC-RRD)
    @ 166 MHz   2.5-3-3-7  (CL-RCD-RP-RAS) / 10-12-2  (RC-RFC-RRD)  
Module Size - 1 GB (2 ranks, 4 banks)

CPU Clock: Intel Pentium 4, 2800 MHz (21 x 133)

OpenGL Version: 1.3.0 - Build 4.14.10.4396
```

So my question is: "If I change AGP Aperture Size to bigger value, will Minecraft work better or not?"
**Edit**
After I change AGP Apertute Size to 256 mb, the performance increased a lot, almost no lags.
Also I changed Fan Idle Mode from 1 to 2 and my motherboard temperature has decreased while playing Minecraft.

Comment: This is probably better for Super User.  That said, aperture size only matters when you're USING THE AGP CARD, and you aren't!  It just allocates internal memory in the machine to be extra GPU memory.  This probably won't make any difference - and more importantly  *Minecraft is probably going to run like crap on this machine*.

Comment: Your question is quite specific, I don't think there are many people nowadays with AGP cards. That being said, it might take some time before someone can really answer your question (or maybe no one can answer it; we don't know yet). Now... Asking your question and 10 minutes later adding a comment complaining doesn't feel very polite. It makes you look you were expecting almost-instant feedback. This not always happens.

Comment: Well try it and you'll see :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minecraft is very unlikely to use that much video memory, and video memory is almost certainly not the bottleneck, so you won't see a meaningful performance increase.

Minecraft is probably CPU-bound on your machine, since you're using a P4 and the Intel chip probably offloads a lot of its processing onto the CPU (I believe many early Intel chips do things like vertex processing on the CPU, even if you select to do it in hardware)

Also, the AGP Aperture size applies to cards connected via AGP only, you'd have to find out if the Intel chip is also connected via AGP (which is unlikely, but possible).

Basically, Minecraft performance is low because your computer is old and slow. If you want better performance, lower your Minecraft settings or upgrade your hardware.